# How to get the values only absent date and absent student id

Tags: php, codeigniter

Here i am doing one attendance module , that means who all are absent, i stored their **id**  in database as json string ,here actually id 1 is absent on **2017-04-11** and **2017-04-12**

---

id 2 is absent **2017-04-11** and **2017-04-13**,upto now working fine, here after what i want to do means , i have one dynamic variable like **loginId=2**, i want to display the results like id 2 is which are the date he is absent, please see below my expected results.

> student_absent_list (**table name**)

```
absendId   studentAbsentId    studentAbsentDate    schoolId

  1          ["1","2"]              2017-04-11        2

  2          ["1"]                  2017-04-12        2

  3          ["2"]                  2017-04-13        2
```

> My Controller

```
public function getAbsentListStaff()
{
    date_default_timezone_set('Asia/Kolkata');
    $loginType = $_POST['loginType'];
        if($loginType == 1)
        {
            $data = array(
            "schoolId" => $_POST['schoolName'],
            "classId" => $_POST['className'],
            "sectionId" => $_POST['sectionName'],
            "loginId" =>$_POST['loginId'],
            );

            $absentresponse= $this->Android_login_model->admin_options_listdisplayparent($data);

            foreach ($absentresponse as $key => $value)
            {
                $absentresponse[$key]->studentAbsentId=  json_decode($value->studentAbsentId,true);
            }

            if($absentresponse){
            $return=array('status'=>"Success",'data'=>$absentresponse);
            echo json_encode($return);
            }
            else{
                $return=array('status'=>"Error",'description'=>"Data Not Found");
              echo json_encode($return);
            } 

        }
}
```

> My Model

```
public function admin_options_listdisplayparent($params)
    { 
        $this->db->select('*');
        $this->db->where('status !=', '1');
        $this->db->where('schoolId =',$params['schoolId']);
        $this->db->where('classId =',$params['classId']);
        $this->db->where('sectionId =',$params['sectionId']);
        //$this->db->where('studentAbsentDate =',$params['absentDate']);
        return $this->db->get('student_absent_list')->result();
    }
```

> My Expected Results

```
     {
      "status": "Success",
      "data": [
        {
          "studentAbsentId":  "2"
          "studentAbsentDate": "2017-04-11",
          "schoolId": "2",
          "response":"absent"
        },

     {
      "studentAbsentId":  "2"
      "studentAbsentDate": "2017-04-13",
      "schoolId": "2",
      "response":"absent"
    }
  ]
}
```

> Updated answer

```
 {
  "status": "Success",
  "data": [
    {
      "absendId": "1",
      "studentAbsentId": [
        "1",
        "2"
      ],
      "studentAbsentDate": "2017-04-11",
      "schoolId": "2",
      "classId": "1",
      "sectionId": "1",
      "reg_date": "2017-04-13 01:01:03",
      "created_by": "kanniyappan@g2evolution.co.in",
      "status": "0"
    },
    {
      "absendId": "2",
      "studentAbsentId": [
        "1"
      ],
      "studentAbsentDate": "2017-04-12",
      "schoolId": "2",
      "classId": "1",
      "sectionId": "1",
      "reg_date": "2017-04-13 01:01:14",
      "created_by": "kanniyappan@g2evolution.co.in",
      "status": "0"
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because StackOverflow is not a free crowd sourced code generator.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Try rewriting your model as below:

```
public function admin_options_listdisplayparent($params)
{
    $condition = array(
        'status !=' => '1',
        'schoolId' => $params['schoolId'],
        'classId' => $params['classId'],
        'sectionId' => $params['sectionId']
    );

    $this->db->select('*');
    $this->db->where($condition);
    $this->db->like('studentAbsentId', '"' . $params['loginId'] . '"', 'both');
    return $this->db->get('student_absent_list')->result();
}
```

> Rewrite Controller as below:

```
public function getAbsentListStaff() {
    date_default_timezone_set('Asia/Kolkata');
    $loginType = $_POST['loginType'];

    if($loginType == 1)
    {
        $data = array(
            "schoolId" => $_POST['schoolName'],
            "classId" => $_POST['className'],
            "sectionId" => $_POST['sectionName'],
            "loginId" =>$_POST['loginId'],
        );

        $absentresponse_data= $this->Android_login_model->admin_options_listdisplayparent($data);
        $absentresponse = array();
        foreach ($absentresponse_data as $res)
        {
            $row = array();
            $row['studentAbsentId'] = $_POST['loginId'];
            $row['studentAbsentDate'] = $res->studentAbsentDate;
            $row['schoolId'] = $res->schoolId;
            $row['response'] = 'absent';

            $absentresponse[] = $row;
        }

        if(count($absentresponse) > 0){

            $return = array('status'=>"Success",'data'=>$absentresponse);
            echo json_encode($return);
        } else {
            $return = array('status'=>"Error",'description'=>"Data Not Found");
            echo json_encode($return);
        } 

    }
}
```

Comment: I AM not getting the expected results,please see my updated answer

Comment: Very very Thanks Mr @Sachin PATIL, i got the solution now